# Get Web Url from offline HTML

Tags: html, url

I'm new on this forum.
In some c++ project, I'm trying to analyse offline HTML files that I previously donwloaded. I need to  get information from these files like the language, the title...eetc. For this, I found ways out.
But I got some tricky problems when I tried to know the original url from where I had downloaded these files. In fact, my application has to be comptelely offline, but I still need the original url.
As i downloaded this files with the mobile Chrome app, some precious information are displayed at the very outset of the source html code, before the DOCTYPE. The original url is given as the "content location" :

```
From <Saved by blink>
Snapshpot-Content-Location: http://adaa-ase.com/savon-champoing-.php#1123
Subject: faire du savon avec de la cendre de bois
etc...
```

But I really doubt these informations are always displayed at the begining of the code. Moreover, this is the way the Chrome App plays it, so... it's not portable.

My question is the following :
How can I find the original url of a HTML file downloaded from the web, no matter which way I got the file (and with what browser) ?

PS: is that the "canonical url" ?

Comment: I don't think there's a reliable way to get this information from an html file. It won't always be available.

Comment: If it's impossible, I'll find another way